# Integrate $\int_{\|x\| \le R} e^{x \cdot y} dx$ using spherical coordinates

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

How  to simplify the following integral using spherical coordinates 
\begin{align}
\int_{\|x\| \le R}  e^{x \cdot y} dx
\end{align}
where $x, y\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

I know how to do this with  cylindrical and spherical coordinates in $n=2$  using the formula $ x \cdot y=\|x\| \|y\| \cos(\theta)$.

Can someone explain how to simplify this integral by using spherical coordinates especially for larger $n$ (i.e. $n>3$ ).

I am specifically interested in how to properly do the change of coordinate systems. Once this is done I can do the integral myself.

Answer (score 0):

You may assume ${\bf y}=\eta\,{\bf e}_n$ with $\eta>0$. Then by Fubini's theorem we have
$$\int_{B_n(R)}e^{{\bf x}\cdot{\bf y}}\>{\rm d}({\bf x})=\int_{-R}^R e^{\eta x_n} \int_{B_{n-1}\bigl(\sqrt{R^2-x_n^2}\bigr)}{\rm d}({\bf x}')\>dx_n\ .$$
Here the inner integral is just the volume of $B_{n-1}\bigl(\sqrt{R^2-x_n^2}\bigr)$.

Comment: Why is it from $-R$ to $R$? Shouldn't it be from $0$ to $R$?

Comment: Sorry, I got that now.